# h:inputText - does not put input in beans?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am coding a jsf-application. Here is my code:

**register.xhtml:**

```
        <fieldset>
            <div>
              <h:outputLabel class="Float" for="username" value="Username"/>
              <h:inputText id="username" rendered="true" value="#{Register.username}" label="Username">
              <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="8"/>
              </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div>
              <h:outputLabel class="Float" for="password" value="Passwort"/>
              <h:inputText id="password" rendered="true" value="#{Register.password}" label="Passwort">
                <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="8"/>
              </h:inputText>
            </div>
       </fieldset>

<div id="buttons">
  <h:form id="buttons">
    <h:commandButton id="enter" accesskey="r" value="Registrieren" action="#{Register.registerPlayer()}" immediate="true"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{msg.wrongpwd}" rendered="#{loginCtrl.loginfailed}" style="color: red"/>
    <h:messages style="color: red"/>
  </h:form>
</div>
</form>
...
```

**Register.java:**

```
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return pwd;
}

public void registerPlayer() {
    this.nameList.add(getUsername());
    this.passwordList.add(pwd);
    System.out.println(getUsername() + " : " + pwd  + " :successfully registered!!!");
}
```

My problem is I get as output when I press the button:

null : null :successfully registeres!!!

Why is this?

**UPDATE 1------------------------------**

ok I used the h:form tag but I still get null back:

here is the cycle I think how the jsf works:
First: write in inputText -> the beans reads it -> you can manipulate that value(ex. write it in a list)...

What wrong with that cycle? or my code...

**UPDATE 2------------------------------**
My setter methods:

```
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public void setPassword(String pwd) {
    this.pwd = pwd;
}
```

They are out of reach, but why?

Comment: Do you have setters for your bean fields, e.g. `setUsername(...)`? Furthermore you normally need to call beans with a lower case first letter (unless you didn't name it explicitely `Register` in your annotation).

Comment: yeah I have setters but I do not call them in my *.xhtml file... Should I call them and if where????;????

Comment: No, they should automatically be called by JSF. You could set a breakpoint inside the setter method and check if it is reached.

Comment: they are not reached, but they still exist? Why does not reach the framework the setters?

Comment: Are you sure you used same form for buttons and inputText elements?

Comment: @user1248720 Your h:inputText must be inside the SAME form that you placed the commandButton

Answer (score 3):

Your `h:inputText` fields must be inside a form. Try following:

```
<h:form>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <h:outputLabel class="Float" for="username" value="Username"/>
            <h:inputText id="username" rendered="true" value="#{Register.username}" label="Username">
                <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="8"/>
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h:outputLabel class="Float" for="password" value="Passwort"/>
            <h:inputText id="password" rendered="true" value="#{Register.password}" label="Passwort">
                <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="8"/>
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div id="buttons">
        <h:commandButton id="enter" accesskey="r" value="Registrieren" action="#{Register.registerPlayer()}" immediate="true"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.wrongpwd}" rendered="#{loginCtrl.loginfailed}" style="color: red"/>
        <h:messages style="color: red"/>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

Now form includes both `inputText` fields and `commandButton`s